# Javascript- Prevent page redirection after validation

Tags: javascript, html

I have a drop down- If user tries to submit the page, but doesn't choose an option from the dropdown, then I want an ALERT message box to appear, then for the page to stay where it is instead of navigating to another page.

Currently, the drop down appears, but the page still redirects to another page. How do I prevent this?

I tried "return false" but it didn't work...

function validateDropDown() {

var e = document.getElementById("colors");
   var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

```
var strColor1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var strColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            if(strColor==0)
            {
                alert("Please select a color");
                return false;//This is what I tried to prevent page redirection, but it doesn't work.
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning `false` inside your function you can use `event.preventDefault()` as explained by W3, it does exactly what you are looking for

```js
function validateDropDown(event) { // add the parameter event 

var e = document.getElementById("services1"); 
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            if(strUser==0) {
                alert("Please select a service");
                event.preventDefault(); // add prevent Default
            }
}
```

## Resources :

[Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Also an explanation of stack overflow exists :

[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Comment: Thanks! I'm still learning JS, so I missed that earlier. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MohanAravind : no problem. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Use prevent default:

```
function validateDropDown(event) {

var e = document.getElementById("services1"); var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            if(strUser==0)
            {
                alert("Please select a service");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
}
```